# Does T matter when passing IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, collections, parameter-passing

Just double checking my understanding on reference/value semantics:

Let's say I made a `List<T> values = new List<T>();`

- If *T* is a **reference** type, then `values` contains a reference to a collection of *T*. However, each element of this collection is then a reference to the data.
- If *T* is a **value** type, then `values` contains a reference to a collection of *T*. However, each element of this collection contains the actual data.

My curiosity arose because I was trying to design a method which required an `IEnumerable<T>`. So if I give it a `List<int>` or a `List<SomeObject>`, it works exactly the same way, the type of *T* is irrelevant and everyone is happy, since it's a *reference to the collection* that is being provided, yes?

```
public sealed class Effect<T>
{
    public void Apply(GameTime time, IEnumerable<T> values)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Also! This has nothing to do with boxing, right? Since `List<T>` has reference semantics, only a struct implementation of `IEnumerable<T>` would involve boxing (but this seems like a disaster waiting to happen)

Comment: In your `Effect` class either the method or the class needs to be generic, i.e. `class Effect<T>` or `void Apply<T>(...)`.

Comment: As long as you don't add `int`s to a `List<object>`, there should be no boxing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding is spot-on.

> My curiosity arose because I was trying to design a method which required an `IEnumerable<T>`. So if I give it a `List<int>` or a `List<SomeObject>`, it works exactly the same way, the type of *T* is irrelevant and everyone is happy, since it's a *reference to the collection* that is being provided, yes?

Yes, `values` is a reference to the collection. This does not affect the nature of its items.

> Also! This has nothing to do with boxing, right? Since `List<T>` has reference semantics, only a struct implementation of `IEnumerable<T>` would involve boxing (but this seems like a disaster waiting to happen)

Yes; the entire point of generic collections is to avoid boxing entirely. Neither the list itself nor its value-type items are boxed (unless the list itself is `List<object>`, in which case, its items are boxed).

Comment: Perfect, I'm glad everything is well. Almost feels like a waste of a question, but hopefully someone else will get something from it. Thanks!